# discord js wait for 1 minute and then continue code

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried using `asyncio.sleep(60);` but doesn't work. Any way to have the thing pause for one minute without the bot going offline?

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}countdown`) {
  console.log('cmd Countdown found');
  if (message.member.roles.find("name", "Queue Master")) {
    let durationString = args.toString();
    var durationInt = parseInt(durationString);
    console.log('starting cd process');
    message.channel.send('Scrim starting in ' + durationString + ' mins');
    for (; durationInt > 0; durationInt--) {
      asyncio.sleep(60);
      durationString = durationInt.toString();
      message.channel.send('Scrim starting in ' + durationString + ' mins');
    }
    if (durationInt === 0) {
      message.channel.send('The host will join the Countdown channel and give you info about the scrim!');
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
(node:4) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: asyncio is not defined
     at Client.bot.on (/app/index.js:100:17)
     at Client.emit (events.js:197:13)
     at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
     at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:137:47)
     at Receiver.dataMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:409:14)
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error explains what the problem is:

```
asyncio is not defined
```

`asyncio` seems to be a Python library, so it doesn't exist in JavaScript.

I suggest [`setTimeout`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setTimeout), or [this Node.js snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038049).